# Matrix inverse property, show that $(I + uv^T)^{-1} = I - \frac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^N, u^Tv \neq -1$. Thereby $I +uv^T \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is invertible. Show that:
>
> $$(I + uv^T)^{-1} = I - \frac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}$$

I'm lost, why did the denominator get $uv^T$ as $v^T u$? Where did this $1$ come from? Any hints are very appreciated!

Comment: Get some ideas from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: The nominator (not denominator) has to be an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: $u v^T$ is the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) and is an $n \times n$ matrix, while $v^T u$ is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and is a ($1 \times 1$) scalar.

Comment: @Thomas [Please use "numerator"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68765/22428) when discussing the top half of a fraction.

Comment: @Clash I think there's a typo in the condition for invertability.  Should be $v^Tu \ne -1$.

Comment: @Andrew, you may be right! I just double checked it and this is how it's written in the exercise. I'm going to fire an email to the exercise creator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not multiply the right side by $I+uv^t$ and see if you get the identity matrix? Note that $v^tu$ is a scalar.

Comment: So, multiplying by $(I + uv^T)$ for the left side I have the identiy matrix. On the right side I'm getting $I - \frac{(uv^T)^2}{1+v^Tu}$. This would only be the identity matrix if $\frac{(uv^T)^2}{1+v^Tu}$ is $0$. Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @Clash multiplying two binomials together (although these aren't exactly binomials) should produce an expression with 4 terms.  You need two more terms.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks! Are the two other terms $uv^T - \frac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}$?

Comment: @Andrew, thanks! I got it now with your help and wikipedia! :) It would take me a while alone however to notice that there was a scalar in the middle of everything that I could factor out.

Comment: That's why I made a point of noting that $v^tu$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:  Let us put $$B:=uv^T\,\,,\,\,w:=v^Tu$$Now, let us do the matrix product$$(I+B)\left(I-\frac{1}{1+w}B\right)=\frac{1}{1+w}(I+B)(I-B+wI)=\frac{1}{1+w}(I-B^2+wI+wB)=$$$$=\frac{1}{1+w}\left[(1+w)I+B(wI-B)\right]$$Well, now just check the product $$B(wI-B)...:>)$$

***Added***$$B^2=\left(uv^T\right)\left(uv^T\right)=u\left(v^Tu\right)v^T=uwv^T=wuv^T=wB$$ so we get $$B(wI-B)=wB-B^2=wB-wB=0$$